# coding with heroku and some addones and sendgrid function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, heroku-toolbelt

Hi i am doing some coding with heroku and now i am running with some problem more specifically using this code in my terminal

```
sudo heroku addones:add sendgrid:starter --app project1
```

end result

```
Adding sendgrid:starter on project1... failed
 !    You do not have access to the app project1.
```

I am a bit new with ubuntu and ruby on rails so i dont have any god idea with this exept with ssh but my main problem is why and how any info or help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're logged into the account that owns/has permissions to project1 by running:

`heroku login`

Also, you have a syntax error in your command, should be:

`heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter --app project1`

Comment: just tried it , and this showed                                                   :~/projects/project1$ heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter --app project1
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/simplybel/.netrc (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: try running with sudo

Comment: hi it also includes sudo because i usually get some admin error

Comment: are you running this locally on your development machine?

Comment: `chmod 755 /home/simplybel/.netrc` then try again

Comment: hi still nada it is giving me this kind of error                    simplybel@simplybel:~/projects/project1$ sudo chmod 755 /home/simplybel/.netrc
simplybel@simplybel:~/projects/project1$ sudo heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter --app project1
Permissions 493 for '/home/simplybel/.netrc' are too open. You should run `chmod 0600 /home/simplybel/.netrc` so that your credentials are NOT accessible by others.

Comment: yeah so run chmod 0600 on that directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65025/discussion-between-bsy-and-user1868185).